# Reorder all strings in a Column of a Dataframe R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, tibble

I'm trying to reorder a string in a dataframe for all of the values in a column.

I have values such as:

```
F123/1K
F234/2Q
F678/8W
```

and I want it to look like:

```
K1231
Q2342
W6788
```

Is there a way to change all the strings at once rather than the crude way of doing each individually in a loop?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture patterns as a group and then do the rearrangement of the backreference of the captured groups in the replacement

```
sub("^.(.{3}).(.)(.)", "\\3\\1\\2", df1$col)
#[1] "K1231" "Q2342" "W6788"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col = c("F123/1K", "F234/2Q", "F678/8W")), 
   .Names = "col", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I think you want to remove the `/` as well

Comment: I'm getting the issue that the whole column is going into the first row:  [1] "3(\"F123/1K\", \"F234/2Q\", \"F678/8W\")

Comment: @MaskedMonkey  I updated with the data and the output I am getting